# How to show my application in Music Equalizer in settings android

Tags: android, audio, audio-player, equalizer, android-music-player

Here i am creating an application handling the `music and audio frequency`, like an `EQUALIZER`. and how to set my application as a `default equalizer`, and how to show my `equalizer application in device settings screen`.

i searched these [classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) but unable to found solution for that.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

Take one activity and declare that activity like this

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="package.ActivityName">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_CONTENT_MUSIC" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: How do you open the equalize intent? i.setAction(android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL) and then startActivityForResult(i, 1234)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL");
    if((intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
        // REQUEST_EQ is an int of your choosing
    } else {
        // No equalizer found :(
    }
```

put any activity where you need

Comment: Hello what is the problem ?